# Get coordinates from polygon points on MapBox draw?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, mapbox-gl-js

This is the code I am using for polygon to draw and I am using MapBox GL draw I am trying to get longitude and latitude of every point from polygon.

```
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
  displayControlsDefault: false,
  controls: {
     polygon: true,
     trash: true,
  }
});

map.addControl(draw);

map.on('draw.create', function(e) { 

    if (lngLat.lng && lngLat.lat == 'polygon') {
        console.log(draw.getAll());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x=draw.getAll();
console.log(x['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0]);
```